I'm receiving errors installing `renv` package. Why?
I am trying to install renv.  I can install other R packages without problems.
I show various error messages below.
I have the secure http option unchecked in RStudio, yet I see some SSL errors.  Why?  I thought this option would make web connections without SSL.
Is there anything else I can try?
Many thanks.

> install.packages("renv")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2222795 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 2212600 != reported length 2222795
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip' failed
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(mirrors_csv_url, destfile = mirrors_csv, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'SSL connect error'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘renv’ failed

> Sys.setenv(RENV_DOWNLOAD_FILE_METHOD = "wininet") # I saw this recommendation elsewhere

> install.packages("renv")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2222795 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 2212600 != reported length 2222795
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘renv’ failed

> install.packages("renv")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2222795 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 2213337 != reported length 2222795
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘renv’ failed

EDIT
I increased the timeout, but still receive this error.
> options(timeout = 600)
> install.packages("renv")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/st2516/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2222795 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 2212942 != reported length 2222795
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/renv_1.0.11.zip' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘renv’ failed


What kind of network are you on? Is this some unusual corporate environment? Is there a http proxy involved?

It could be a timeout issue...

Try a different CRAN mirror for starters.   Try installing from the command line instead of trudging through the Rstudio interface.

It is a corporate environment with a Firewall and VPN.  However, I haven't had any issues until now.  I did try also to install from the R application instead of RStudio, but I think perhaps RStudio http setting is a useful feature that I miss from the R app.

It looks like it is timing out after 1 minute, and the full package was not downloaded yet. Try a mirror closer to you or increase the timeout limit, e.g. options(timeout = 600).

Change your download time using the options junction. The default is 60 seconds. Double or triple it. See the `?download.files’ help page.

I appreciate the ideas.  I increased timeout, but still receive an error.  I edited my question to include this.
